# HttpClient exception localhost.fiddler

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, httpclient, fiddler

In my ASP.NET MVC application I use service hosted on localhost:33321, I try to monitor traffic using fiddler.

When I type address localhost.fiddler:33321 in web browser service is opens to but when I use service in app I get exeptions from HttpClient

> Unable to find 'localhost.fiddler'

I think that problem is related to DNS service or fiddler local proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution are described here:

http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureDotNETApp 
http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/MonitorLocalTraffic

Steps:

Set address to service:
http://localhost.fiddler:33321

Set proxy in web.config

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy autoDetect="false" bypassonlocal="false" proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" usesystemdefault="false" />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```